# Difference between two similarly-named books - 'The Bear Who Wanted to [Be|Stay] a Bear'

Tags: identification-request, title

My daughter told me she wants to read the book *The Bear Who Wanted to Stay a Bear* by Jörg Steiner with me, probably after reading it at school.  Google yields search results for these differently-but-similarly-named books:

- *[The Bear Who Wanted to Be a Bear](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1970097.The_Bear_Who_Wanted_to_Be_a_Bear)*
- *[The Bear Who Wanted to Stay a Bear](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1970102.The_Bear_Who_Wanted_to_Stay_a_Bear)*

This Wikipedia article on yet another book, *[The Bear That Wasn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bear_That_Wasn%27t)*, mentions the *Be* version of the title as the English-language translation of the Swiss-German adaptation.  What is the difference between *Be* and *Stay*?  Are they different translations by different translators, such that my daughter would come cross slighly different passages should I get the *Be* version (after having insisted to me that the title is *Stay a Bear*, not *Be a Bear*)?

Comment: your two `goodreads` links show two editions of the same book. In `goodreads` 15 editions in different languages are added for the book. If you scroll both pages down you see the same reviews etc. And you see that the original title is "Der Bär, der ein Bär bleiben wollte", it may be translated in different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The Bear Who Wanted to Stay a Bear* is published by Andersen Press, which is a U.K. publisher.

*The Bear Who Wanted to Be a Bear* is published by Heryin Books, Inc., which is a U.S. publisher.

This then appears to be two editions of a book with a slightly different name in the U.K. and the U.S., like *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's/Sorcerer's Stone.*

It's entirely possible that they have some minor textual differences; it's even possible, though quite unlikely, that they were translated by different translators.

Finally, under the comments on *The Bear who Wanted to Be a Bear* at Goodreads, someone included the following paragraph:

> 2012 Update:
>
> I ordered a copy from Amazon to give myself for Christmas and found the translation has been altered in two horrible ways. First, what was "lazybones" in my 1980s version is now the infinitely less pleasing "slacker." Also, THE LAST SENTENCE HAS BEEN ELIMINATED! The last page used to read, "And then he remembered." But no longer! Now the end feels so much more disturbing and death-like. Not to mention confusing. My mother used to shamelessly alter my children's books to be less sexist and I'd encourage all owners of this book to add in the last line by hand.

So certainly some editions have textual differences; I don't know whether this is a difference between the two versions with different titles, or whether the American publisher actually changed the text.

ADDED: This book has been turned into a song in French: *L'ours qui voulait rester un ours*. [Performed here](https://www.flashlyrics.com/lyrics/frederik-mey/lours-qui-voulait-rester-un-ours-81); [words here](https://www.flashlyrics.com/lyrics/frederik-mey/lours-qui-voulait-rester-un-ours-81). And judging by this version, the last line "and then he remembered" was not in the original German. I would assume that it was put into the first American edition by the editors to keep the ending from being too ambiguous or sad. So it was removed so as to stay truer to the original.

Answer (score 0):

Both Google results you indicate in the question are links to [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/) (a site for readers and book recommendations), in fact, they show two editions of the same book. Currently, different 15 editions are added for this book. If you scroll both pages down you see the same reviews etc. And you see that the original title in German is "Der Bär, der ein Bär bleiben wollte", it may be translated in different ways.
The Wikipedia article for another book [The Bear That Wasn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bear_That_Wasn%27t) (1946) you mention says that it

> inspired Swiss writer Jörg Steiner to create his children's book *Der
> Bär, der ein Bär bleiben wollte* (1976;

namely, this same book from Goodreads.